# Issue installing symfony 3.0 on mac

Tags: macos, symfony

I am trying to install symfony 3.0 on my macos.
According to their official website, I need to type on my console:

```
$ sudo curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

then I type my password
and then I type:

```
$ sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

and then, according to the official symfony documentation, there is nothing more simple than typing;

```
$ symfony new my_project_name
```

but my console returns a red message that says:

```
Task "new" is not defined.
```

This is probably because I already had an old version of symfony installed on my machine, but I am not sure

The problem is that I see little documentation around this.

Comment: if you try `/usr/local/bin/symfony new my_project_name`

Comment: no. new is stil not defined. I managed to create a new project with composer though...  `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name "3.0.0"`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are pointing on an old version of the installer.
You can check if is the lastest version with the `--version` option:

```
>symfony --version
```

You can update your current version as following:

1) update your installer

```
>symfony self-update
```

or with sudo, depends how you install it:

```
>sudo symfony self-update
```

2) Then try again:

```
>symfony new my_project_name
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hi Matteo. I have version 1.4.2 of symfony installed in my machine and unfortunately, it does not recognize the task "self-update" (it says Task "self-update" is not defined).

Comment: Hi @camilo, of course, the old console command of sf1 can't support this. If you want to support both i suggest you to install the symfony2 installer with a different name as example `sudo curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony2` hope this work for you